# Multiple select validation not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a multiple select box and I am using CI to validate drop down with custom CI validation library. But it's always produce string while its produce an array of selected items.

```
<select multiple="" class="form-control" name="course[]" id="course">
    <option value="">Select Course</option>
    <option value="38833851">B.com</option> 
    <option value="31068174">B.Sc Nursing</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="7771143">B.Tech</option>
</select>
```

and in controller

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('course[]', 'course name','required|multiple_select');
```

and other thing. I have created a another custom validation library.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{
    protected $CI;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function multiple_select($array){
        print_r($array); die;
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('multiple_select', 'Select at least one %s');
        if(empty($array)){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

But `$array` always print a string.

Please provide any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I took the code you provided and rebuilt the scenario in codeigniter. It would appear that there is a conflict with the documentation and the particular codeigniter version you are running (and myself apparently as I was able to duplicate your issue). In the documentation it tells you to use empty brackets in the form validation configuration line like below:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('options[]', 'Options', 'required');
```

However the only way I was able to recieve the array value in the validation function was to NOT include the empty array brackets within the form validation set rules function. Below is your original line with the brackets removed:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('course', 'course name','required|multiple_select');
```

Changing this line resulted in the array values being passed to the validation function as expected.

Comment: thanks for your answer but string is not comma separated. its produce only one selected item

Comment: you are saying that when you select multiple items from the list, only one is being sent to the validation function?

Comment: exactly. thats the main issue.

Comment: I think you are right their is problem with CI version. But when i am using your solution nothing get in $array. Its empty.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Codeigniter Callback:

```
public function multiple_select()
{
     $arr_course = $this->input->post('course[]');
     if(empty($arr_course)):
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('course','Select at least one course');
        return false;
     endif;
}
```

And in your controller

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('course[]', 'course name','required|callback_multiple_select');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am using this code multiple time in many controllers so i created a separated library.